# setTimeout executes itself right away/on clear

Tags: javascript

I'm making a webpage where user events are logged in.
To test the feature I made a small, independant webpage with a teaxtarea and a text input. The events logged are those performed on the `input` element.

I want to prevent the same event text to be shown multiple times in a row, but I can't seem to prevent them from showing up!

I also want to add a line to separate event groups 0.5 seconds after no other event happened, but the line seems to appear on every event trigger, evenif I use `clearTimeout` with the timeout ID.

Basically: I don't want any line to be repeated. If the last line is a separator line, then it must not add another one. Yet it doesn't see to work.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6kb4/2/)**

Here is my code:

### JavaScript

```
var timerID = 0;

function addSeparateLine()
{
  document.getElementById('listeEvenements').value += "--------------------\n";
}

function show(newEventText)
{
  var eventListField = document.getElementById('listeEvenements');
  var eventList = [];

  if (eventListField.value.length > 0)
  {
    eventList = eventListField.value.split("\n");
  }

  var eventCounter = eventList.length;
  if (eventList[eventCounter - 2] == newEventText)
  {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    newEventText = "";
  }

  timerID = setTimeout(addSeparateLine, 500);

  if (newEventText !== "")
  {
    eventListField.value += newEventText + "\n";
  }

  return true;
}
```

### HTML

```
<fieldset id="conteneurLogEvenements">
  <legend>Events called from HTML attribute</legend>
  <textarea id="listeEvenements" rows="25"></textarea>
  <input id="controleEcoute" type="text" onBlur="show('Blur');" onchange="show('Change');" onclick="show('Click');" onfocus="show('Focus');" onMousedown="show('MouseDown');" onMousemove="show('MouseMove');" onMouseover="show('MouseOver');" onkeydown="show('KeyDown');"
  onkeypress="show('KeyPress');" onkeyup="show('KeyUp');" />
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6kb4/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z6kb4/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a line that prints after 500 milliseconds of inactivity, but what your code currently says to do is "print a line 500 milliseconds after any action, unless it gets canceled".  You can get better results by structuring the code more closely to your intended goal.

Specifically, instead of scheduling a new timeout every time an event occurs, simply start a loop when the *first* event occurs that checks the time that has elapsed since the most recent event received and then prints a line when the elapsed time exceeds the desired threshold (500 milliseconds).  Something like:

```
function addSeparateLine() {
    var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - lastEventTime;
    if (elapsed >= 500) {
        document.getElementById('listeEvenements').value += "--------------------\n";
        clearInterval(timerID);
        timerID = -1;
    }
}
```

...and then you schedule it like:

```
if(newEventText !== "") {
    lastEventTime = new Date().getTime();
    eventListField.value += newEventText+"\n";
    if (timerID == -1) {
        timerID = setInterval(addSeparateLine,100);
    }
}
```

Working example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/z6kb4/4/

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not actually stopping the `show` function in any way. The `clearTimeout` only applies to the separator add. I have [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6kb4/6/). You need to wrap your function with

```
if (+new Date() - lastfire < 500) return;
```

and

```
lastfire = +new Date();
```

(before the last return--see the updated fiddle). Also, make sure to stick the global definition `var lastfire = -1;` somewhere up top.